# Trash elements in array [C]

Tags: c

```
    while (arr[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (((arr[i] == '/' && arr[i + 1] == '*') || 
                (arr[i] == '*' && arr[i + 1] == '/') || 
                (arr[i] == '*' && arr[i - 1] == '/') || 
                (arr[i] == '/' && arr[i - 1] == '*')) 
                || (arr[i] == ' ' || arr[i] == '\t' || arr[i] == '\r' ||
                    arr[i] == '\n' || arr[i] == '\v' || arr[i] == '\f'))
                flag_char = 0;

            if (arr[i] == '/' && arr[i + 1] == '*' && flag_comment == 0)
                flag_comment = 1;

            if (arr[i] == '*' && arr[i + 1] == '/' && flag_comment == 1)
                flag_comment = 0;

            if (flag_comment == 1 && flag_char == 1)
            {
                characters++;
                flag_char = 1;

            }
            else
                flag_char = 1;
            i++;
       }
```

So i'm trying to count the characters in a multi line comment. If i do something like /* asd */ it counts 3 characters, but if i do

```
/*
asd
*/
```

It won't count any characters, because of some trash elements the array is filled with. When it gets to 'a'arr[i-1] shows some character instead of \n.
How can i get rid of it? I'm getting the characters with fgets:

```
while (fgets(arr, 100, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            if (strstr(arr, "Terminate")) break;
            getCount(arr); // that's my function name
        }
```

Comment: How did you fill `arr`?

Comment: I used fgets for it.

Comment: `fgets` reads only _one_ line at a time, so you are feeding your `getCount()` with `"/*\n"`, `"asd\n"` and then `"*/\n"`.

Comment: So I assume there's no way to do it while using fgets? And why does my code think it's out of comments when the second line come?

Comment: Well, you can keep reading the lines till a `"*/"` is encountered...